# Как задать ширину контейнера PyQt5?(Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qlayout

У меня есть код, который я оставлю ниже.

Класс `Label()` принимает путь к изображению и закругляет его края. Из-за некоторых обстоятельств буду использовать его экземпляры вместо кнопок.

В классе `MyWindow()` я создаю два `QGridLayout'а` - `box1` и `box3` и один `QVBoxLayout` - `box2`.

1. В `box2` добавляю кнопку `button`.
2. `box3` наполняю двумя виджетами `QLabel`,
   которые получаю из класса `Label()`.
3. `box2` и `box3` помещаю в `box1`.

Первый виджет QLabel `label1` использую вместо кнопки - привязываю к нему метод `click()`, который очищает контейнер `box3` и создает внутри него новую кнопку.

Если начать увеличивать размер окна, то размер QVBoxLayout то же начинает увеличиваться. Но, почему-то, если нажать на `label1`, вызвав метод `click`, который очищает `box3`, содержимое контейнера `box2` прилипнет к правой стенке окна. Хотел бы понять, почему это происходит, но это не самое главное, что я хотел спросить.

**Я хочу зафиксировать ширину контейнера `box2` (высоту мне нужно оставить изменяемой при масштабировании окна), чтобы было понятнее, нарисовал схему:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1)
        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')
        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.box3.setSpacing(20)
        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box3, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box3.columnCount()):
                w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()

        self.box3.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне это сделать?

Comment: вы забыли прикрепить код

Comment: Опять забыл:( Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Кладете эти картинки на QWidget (c QHBoxLayout), справа и слева от этого QWidget вставляете по QSpacerItem

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, а у вас нет под рукой примера, где кладут картинки на QWidget? Просто не совсем понимаю

Comment: Или вы имеете в виду положить контейнер с картинками в  QHBoxLayout?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, мне кажется, что  `QSpacerItem` для данного вопроса не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я конечно извиняюсь, но я расставил строки в классе MyWindow как мне удобнее и понятнее.
Т.е. сразу виджеты, а потом Layout'ы.

Я добавил `setStyleSheet` во все виджеты, чтобы вы видели, где они расположены и сколько места занимают.
Уберете их потом.

По сути:

1. прибил :) `self.button` к правой стороне `alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight`
2. добавил `AlignCenter`
   `self.box1.addLayout(self.box3, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)`
3. добавил `self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)`

   > QGridLayout::setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch). 
   >   Читать здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button') 
        self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color: #0f0;')

        self.label1 = Label('head3.png')
        self.label1.setStyleSheet('background-color: #0ff;')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.label2 = Label('Ok.png')
        self.label2.setStyleSheet('background-color: #8ff;')

        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')
        self.new_button.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ff0;')

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)        # +++

        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.box3.setSpacing(20)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1) 

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box3, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)       # +++
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)                                        # +++
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box3.columnCount()):
                w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()
        self.box3.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!